# Django search the wrong directory for index template

Tags: python, django

Hi I'm new at Django and i have 2 app named home and blog.

my home project urls.py is

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('home.urls')),
    path('blog/',include('blog.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

blog apps urls.py is

```
app_name= 'blog'
urlpatterns =[
    path('',views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('<int:post_id>/',views.postpage, name ='postpage')
]
```

home apps urls.py is

```
app_name= 'home'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

and when i try to render index.html in home app, django search in blog app however it must search in home app.

more detail my home views.py is

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,'home/index.html')
```

and page return

TemplateDoesNotExist at /

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/caglarbingol/Documents/Projects/caglarbingol/blog/templates/home/index.html (Source does not exist)

two app have both index.html page in dir

blog/templates/blog/index.html and
home/templates/home/index.html

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It must because of the Settings you saved for the template directory. Can you share your settings.py file code containing the TEMPLATE list? Also the project directory tree?

Comment: I forgot to add home app to settings.py. It solve my problem. Many thanks to you @AjayLingayat

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no copy paste error in your post/view.py? You provided only the home/views.py.

I suppose in your post/view.py you have the wrong path:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,'home/index.html')
```

Should be

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,'blog/index.html')
```

Comment: no there is not. post/index give this django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/caglarbingol/Documents/Projects/caglarbingol/blog/templates/post/index.html (Source does not exist)

Comment: sorry my mistake ... I correcte "post" to "blog"